# Justification of test cases

Tags: unit-testing, testing

Hi guys I have been asked to write a justification of my test cases that traces back to business rules, data dictionary and data volume requirements.

but the thing is I have no idea how to write a justification for my test cases, I have my test cases done, I have created my own loaded test data all I need is to justify my test cases.

edited: sorry forgot to ask the question, my question is how do you normally write a justification for your test cases?

Comment: We cannot do that work for you, it's you who know the business rules, and the test cases, etc. What is your specific question?

Comment: should be something for programmers.stackxchange.com

Comment: sorry i forgot to ask my question in that post.

Comment: How do you write a justification for a test case?

Comment: Ask back the one who asked you. Tell them you need help to learn and do this task.

Answer (score 3):

This means you must just write why the test case is relevant. You can do lot of unuseful tests. Justify why this one in particular is useful.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO, Aaron.

A few things here...

1. Why do you need to justify your test cases?  As a software tester, you are tasked with being a consumer advocate; **you** are the voice and representative of your end-user(s).
2. If you have all the information you needed to write the test cases themselves, isn't that enough to 'justify' them?
3. Who is asking for this justification?
4. How robust is your coverage?  Are you targeting all the use cases laid out in the business rules?
5. What environment are you testing in?  Are you an agile shop, waterfall...?

Answer (score 0):

First off, do you have a list of applicable rules? It really helps to have an indexed set of business rules:

```
BR.CND.SAL.RNG: Candidates must have a salary within the range of the position.
BR.CND.SAL.BND: Candidates must have a salary bounded by HR guidelines
```

The indexes don't matter, just the fact that you can reference them from elsewhere is what's important. Then your justification for a test case that checks salary values would reference these two business rules.

Data dictionary entries are just as easy to do. Again, it helps to have a way to cross-link to the dictionary. You might have several dozen tests for a particular field, checking min and max values, garbage values, well-formed but invalid values, etc. All unit tests would reference the dictionary entry.

Data volume requirements would be similar: find the listed requirements and reference them.

There are also internal programmatic requirements that you would test as well. These include uniqueness constraints, foreign key constraints, ordering constraints, default value settings. These require justification as well, but the statement "internal software requirement" should be sufficient.